# get values of image src in 2 fields

Tags: php, function, split

I have images src like `"http://www.abc.net/images/bhuvnesh.jpg"`

I want to add -o at the last of image src e.g `"http://www.abc.net/images/bhuvnesh-o.jpg"`

how to split these values from last '.' (dot) and can have jpg in one variable and rest in other variable.

Is there any function of php to get it.

O/p - I need two variable in first variable = http://www.abc.net/images/bhuvnesh
and second variable = jpg

so I can add -o in first variable and then can concat the two.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple way:

```
<?php

$str = "http://www.abc.net/images/bhuvnesh.jpg";
$parts = pathinfo($str);
$filename_without_extension = $parts["dirname"] . "/" . $parts["filename"];
$extension = $parts["extension"];
echo $filename_without_extension . "\n" . $extension;

?>
```

Output:

```
http://www.abc.net/images/bhuvnesh
jpg
```

Then to get the result you want:

```
$result = $filename_without_extension . "-o." . $extension;
```

Comment: @Bhuvnesh Yeah, you can use string manipulation techniques, but it's sometimes easier to use functions built for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()` function for this.

```
$data = explode(".", 'http://www.abc.net/images/bhuvnesh.jpg');
print_r($data); //print array
```

For more detail http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: it will explode complete data but I need to variables in first http://www.abc.net/images/bhuvnesh and in second jpg

Comment: str_replace('http://www.','',http://www.abc.net/images/bhuvnesh'); or try more explode with respect to '/'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of **`str_replace`**?

```
<?php
$str = "http://www.example.net/images/bhuvnesh.jpg";
echo str_replace(".jpg","-o.jpg",$str);
```

### Edit

Separating and concatenating will be just an extra overhead. You can do like below. It works on any image format.

```
<?php
$str = "http://www.example.net/images/bhuvnesh.png";
echo substr_replace($str,'-o.',strrpos($str,'.'),strlen($str+1));
```

Comment: it was a good way.but I just use one example of jpg it can be any image format.I got my answer below.anyways thanks

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta, Below single line of code works for any format. You don't have to accept this as answer , this is another simple way using a single line of code. Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

:) You can replace last dot by "-o.".

```
$newname=preg_replace('/\.jpg$/','-o.jpg','http://www.abc.net/images/bhuvnesh.jpg');
```